# Вызов window.open в IE

Tags: javascript, html

Создал отдельный файл script.js

```
function opens()
{
    window.open('open.html');
}
```

Подключил его к html, во всех браузерах всё нормально, кроме IE. Вот код:

```
<input type="button" name="form_reristr" id="form_registr" onClick="opens()"  value="open">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем большое спасибо.
Как оказалось, всё дело в строке

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

которая отключает javascript, если файл находится не на сервере, а просто на компе.

Вообще это строка нужна для того. чтоб блокировать сообщение IE о том, что есть опасное содержимое и вопросом разрешить его использовать или нет.

После загрузки файла на хостинг всё стало нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, эта статья Вам поможет: [различия в поведении window.open в разных браузерах](http://habrahabr.ru/post/20916/).